# Smoothing Edges of a Stain

Tags: materials, node-editor

How is it possible to smooth the edges of a blur of an image, through material nodes?

It must be after the node color Ramp which cannot be changed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Blurring a color in the shader would require sampling its surroundings, which is a very expensive operation. While you could add the color output of a noise function to the uv coordinates and thus randomize them (making them unsharp), there is no clean solution to this problem.

I'd recommend blurring the texture in an image editor. You don't even need two image nodes as you can de-blur the image again using the threshold of the color ramp.